# Docker container to container communication

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to have my 'app-1' container communicate with my redis 'cache-1' container

I have defined a network in my compose file, but I cannot figure out what I am missing.

[image]

```
version: '2'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    networks:
     - my-net
    
    volumes: 
      - cache:/data
  app:
    image: console-app-demo
    depends_on:
    - redis

volumes:
  cache:
    driver: local

networks:
  my-net:
```

The error message:

```
Unhandled exception. StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). Error connecting right now. To allow this multiplexer to continue retrying until it's able to connect, use abortConnect=false in your connection string or AbortOnConnectFail=false; in your code.
```

I am sure that my issue is simple.
In my console app (C#) program.cs I connect doing:

```
var redisOpstions = new RedisCacheOptions
{
    Configuration = "redis:6379",
    InstanceName = "redis-1."
};
```

Please, what am I missing?

Comment: There is no container named `redis`. You probably meant `cache` (this holds also true for the `RedisCacheOptions`).

Comment: Ahhh the compose is working - thanks but I still get a connection error.
I have edited my question content

Comment: Please do not edit the post and change the core question; the edit would invalidate an existing answer. I rolled back your change. You are free to as a new question.

Comment: @turing85 but my real question is connectivity with the containers within...my first post was too silly for me not to notice... My core question is getting my containers to be able to communicate with each other. app-1 connecting to cache-1.

Comment: Create a new post then.

Comment: @Turing85 For real? That would make a redundant question where the essence of the question is repeated. It was even a comment from you and not an answer.

Comment: Yes for real. You ask a question. It got answered. The answer is correct. Changing the question invalidates the existing answer. This might lead to downvotes on the answer.

Comment: In all versions of the question, the `networks:` of the two containers disagree; one is on a user-defined network and the other on the Compose-provided `default` network.  I'd recommend deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file, which may resolve one of the issues.

Comment: I got it resolved yesterday. I accept the answer even though it wasn't the main question nor the main issue. It was related to my networks section in the yaml file as @DavidMaze also stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In compose-file, depends_on should be name of the service. Your service is named `cache` but your'e providing the image name `redis`; hence the error.